# Legal issue - Game Bot calling functions of copyrighted game

Tags: memory, executable

I spent some time reversing game client of one popular game. Found out multiple functions, ways to make character move, attack, reversed structures containing world data, and so created logic which makes the character grind effectively 24/7.

Now, the legal questions come in. I've read tiny bit about dmca, the glider bot case, but in the end, if i dont share the knowledge of internal game structure, i do not modify (crack, dump) the executeable, just load a dll which calls appropriate functions and reads memory containing surrounding world information, is it illegal? What if i would like to distribute (sell) it to bigger audience?

And second question. If the game is really buggy and leaves many decission to client side (so the server takes things on belief), and so i can make the character move and hit 10 times faster by spamming function calls, is it considered as illegal?

Consider game has a function
auto AttackMonster = (int(__fastcall*)(MonsterContainer*, void*, int monsterIndex))HardcodedAddressIFoundByReversing;

And so calling it repeatidly causes client to send attack request to server without performing the attack speed / cooldown checks, resulting in the character killing everything in a light speed granting huge advantage over other players. What about legality with this one?

So to sum up: All my bot does is: load implant, read memory, call functions from game executeable. No patching no dumping ( no " illegal things " i'd like to say... :) )

Thanks in advance for answers and clarification

Comment: Please see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/law/info

Comment: Oh thats what i was looking for! I wondered why "legal" tag didnt work here. But it has much to do with RE too anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any LEGAL issues with what you're doing so long as you don't publish / distribute anything.

You are of course breaking the EULA, so do expect to get banned if they catch you.

Just to clarify, I'm not a lawyer so don't take anything I say for certain.

This sounds pretty hilarious if what you say is true. I'm curious as to what "popular game" has such horrible security.

Comment: Its MU Online. It used to be popular like 5 years ago, but its still not dead :)